# Intuition behind direction of maximum variance?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I'm trying to understand the phrase "direction of maximum variance" which keeps popping up in the context of PCA.

For example, in this set of 2D points, it is clear they approximately lie on a line. If I could only choose one dimension on which to represent these points it would be that line -- but why does that make this line the direction of maximum variance?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project points orthogonally onto that line.  Measure position along that line as distance from some point chosen to serve as the origin.  Ask what the variance is, or the standard deviation.  Now draw a line at a right angle to that and do the same.  Clearly you see far less dispersion.

All of this depends on the word "orthogonal" making sense.  Imagine measuring the $y$ variable in kilograms and the $x$ variable in dollars.  You can't say a certain number of kilograms equals a certain number of dollars, so there is no privileged aspect ratio, and changing the aspect ratio changes which lines are orthogonal to which.